# How to QUERY Neo4J using .NET Client WithParms instead of injections?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I want to avoid using injection of parms in the query statement. Therefore we used the following instructions from the NEO4J .NET client class:

```
        var queryClassRelationshipsNodes = client.Cypher
                       .Start("a", (NodeReference)sourceReference.Id)
                        .Match("a-[Rel: ***{relationshipType***}    ]->foundClass")
                         .Where("Rel.RelationStartNode  =" + "\'" + relationshipStart + "\'")
                         .AndWhere("Rel.RelationDomainNode  =" + "\'" + relationshipDomain + "\'")
                         .AndWhere("Rel.RelationClassNode  =" + "\'" + relationshipClass + "\'")
                         .WithParam("relationshipType", relationshipType)
                        .Return<Node<Dictionary<string, string>>>("foundClass")
                        .Results;
```

However this code does not work once executed by the server. For some reason the PARM: relationshipType is not connected with the variable which we put in between {}.

Can someone please help us debug the problem with this code? We would prefer to use WithParms rather than injecting variables inside the statement.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please help us debug the problem with this code?

There's a section on https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/wiki/cypher titled "Debugging" which describes how to do this.

As for your core problem though, your approach is hitting a Cypher restriction. Parameters are for parts of the query that aren't compiled into the query plan. The match clause is however.

From [the Neo4j documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9/cypher-parameters.html):

> Parameters can be used for literals and expressions in the WHERE clause, for the index key and index value in the START clause, index queries, and finally for node/relationship ids. Parameters can not be used as for property names, since property notation is part of query structure that is compiled into a query plan.

You could do something like:

```
.Match("a-[Rel:]->foundClass")
.Where("type(Rel) = {relationshipType}")
.WithParam("relationshipType", relationshipType)
```

(Disclaimer: I've just typed that here. I haven't tested it at all.)

That will likely be slower though, because you need to retrieve all relationships, then test their types. You should test this. There's a reason why the match clause is compiled into the query plan.